# Multiline regex find third div in div group

Tags: regex, visual-studio

How can I write a regular expression to find the third div class name in a group div? So in the instance below, I'd like to find **clsA3**

```
<div class="clsA">
  <div class=clsA1">blah</div>
  <div class=clsA2">blah</div>
  <div class=clsA3">blah</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use Visual Studio 2013 Search and Replace using Regular Expression option. The purpose of this task is one-time maintenance task.

Comment: You mean this https://regex101.com/r/rX5eE5/4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Works with VS2010. Not sure if VS2013 does normal regex yet.

Find:

```
{\<div class=[^>]*\>[ \n]*(\<div class=[^>]*\>[^<]*\</div\>[ \n]*)^2\<div class="@}[^">]+{"@\>[^<]*\</div\>[ \n]*\</div\>}
```

Replace:

```
\1Hello World\2
```

Output:

```
<div class="clsA">
  <div class=clsA1">blah</div>
  <div class=clsA2">blah</div>
  <div class=Hello World">blah</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *VS2013 does normal regex yet* If I remember correctly, starting from VS 2012, it uses .NET's Regex.